# Hazelcast IMap - What can be the most efficient way to get value for multiple keys?

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Use Case:
IMap and has 70K entries. Majority of operations are GET call for multiple keys. GET calls (90%) > PUT calls (10%). We are using EP for PUT calls.

Problem: What can be the most efficient way to get the data for multiple keys which can be present across multiple instances?

Possible Solution:
1. EP with ReadOnly, Offloadable and use executeOnKeys method.
2. parallely execute map.get(key) for all keys.

Is there any other efficient way to get the data for multiple keys?

3. Predicate

   public class ExecuteOnSelectedKeyPredicateTest {
              public static void main(String[] args) {
               HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();

   ```
           IMap<String, Integer> map = hazelcastInstance.getMap("testMap");

           map.put("testKey1", 1);
           map.put("test", 2);
           map.put("testKey3", 3);

           // Get entries which ends with a number
           Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entries = map.entrySet(new ExecuteOnSelectedKeyPredicate("^.+?\\d$"));

           System.out.println(entries);
       }

       public static class ExecuteOnSelectedKeyPredicate implements Predicate<String, Integer> {

           private String keyRegex;
           private transient Pattern pattern;

           public ExecuteOnSelectedKeyPredicate(String keyRegex) {
               this.keyRegex = keyRegex;
           }


           @Override
           public boolean apply(Map.Entry<String, Integer> mapEntry) {
               if (pattern == null) {
                   pattern = Pattern.compile(keyRegex);
               }
               Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mapEntry.getKey());
               return matcher.matches();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Getting multiple keys the request has to possibly go to multiple members. `executeOnKeys` is pretty optimal here, since it calculates the partitions the operations needs to be executed on, and it sends that operation to these partitions only. 
Offloadable makes sure you don't block the partitionThreads and ReadOnly optimizes the processing further.

Multiple `get` operations will generate more network traffic, since you have one operation per key.

Comment: @tombujok  - Do you think predicate will perform better than E.P. implementation? I have added code above.

Comment: @tombujok - There is 1 more implementation for IMap - getAll(Set<keys>). Do you think it will be more efficient then EP implementation?

Comment: Hiten, if the only logic that you execute is a read than getAll should be pretty similar. It works in the same way as executeOnKeys in terms of the number of operations that are being sent, so there should not be much of a difference. I remember that your use-case had a write logic too, so it may be better to use the EP to have an unified logic.

Comment: @tombujok - Its possible some entries doesn't exist in the cache. We don't want to use MapStore functionality because it will be read through & block the partition thread. In that case we can't use executeOnKeys / getAll. Can we somehow use Callable to execute on multiple entries? Callable will check if the entry exist or not & if not then load into the cache. By this approach it will not block the partition thread.